# Get mongodb:// credential for SSL Secure Setup

Tags: mongodb

Our Mongo Cluster is ssl secured using a self signed certificate. Below URL works fine while connecting to mongo shell.

```
mongo --host testserver --port 27017 --authenticationMechanism PLAIN --authenticationDatabase='$external' --username test --password tester123 --ssl --sslCAFile /opt/mongo/certs/test-ca.pem
```

While converting this to mongodb:// type connection string, we have tried numerous options like below but getting errors:

```
mongo "mongodb://test:tester123@testserver:27017/?authSource="'$external'"&authMechanism=PLAIN&ssl=true&sslCAFile='/opt/mongo/certs/test-ca.pem'"
```

Error:

```
connecting to: mongodb://testserver:27017/?authMechanism=PLAIN&authSource=%24external&gssapiServiceName=mongodb&ssl=true&sslCAFile=%27%2Fopt%2Fmongo%2Fcerts%2Ftest-ca.pem%27
2020-02-26T06:01:55.936+0000 E NETWORK  [js] SSL peer certificate validation failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain
2020-02-26T06:01:55.937+0000 E QUERY    [js] Error: couldn't connect to server testserver:27017, connection attempt failed: SSLHandshakeFailed: SSL peer certificate validation failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:344:17
@(connect):3:6
exception: connect failed
```

Tried many options like `sslValidate=true`, `sslPEMKeyFile='/opt/mongo/test-ca.pem'`, but all are giving same error.

Comment: What is the value of CN property in your certificate?

Comment: Same as server name. testserver

Comment: Why do you have singe quote around `sslCAFile` path? also around `authSource` value?

Comment: Because mongo "mongodb://test:tester123@testserver:27017/?authSource=$external&authMechanism=PLAIN&ssl=true&sslCAFile=/opt/mongo/certs/test-ca.pem" gives FailedToParse: Missing value for key 'authSource' in the options

Comment: What happens if you manually enter the value of your authSource instead of using `$external`?

Comment: Could you also try this `mongo "mongodb://test:tester123@testserver:27017/?authSource='$external'&authMechanism=PLAIN&ssl=true&sslCAFile=/opt/mongo/certs/test-ca.pem"`